# Spring Websocket with SockJS Connection Lost Issue

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-websocket, sockjs

I'm developing a web application using spring boot, angular cli and sockjs.

WebSocket implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/info", "/user", "/notif");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

Angular websocket util implementation:

**Note: This class is used to connect web socket and subscribe routines!**

```
@Injectable()
export class WebSocketUtil {

  stompClient = null;

  constructor() {
  }

  connect(subscribers: Subscriber[] = null) {
    let _this = this;
    let socket = new SockJS("https://localhost/ws");
    if (socket != null) {
      this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
      if (this.stompClient != null) {
        console.log("Stomp client is connected!");

        let headers = {};
        headers["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] = ...;// csrf code

        this.stompClient.connect(headers, (frame) => {
          subscribers.forEach((subscriber) => {
            _this.stompClient.subscribe(subscriber.URL, subscriber.CALLBACK);
          });
        }, () => {
          console.log(_this.stompClient);
        });
      } else {
        throw {
          name: "StompClientNotRegistered",
          message: "Stomp client is not registered!"
        };
      }
    } else {
      throw {
        name: "SocketEstablishFailed",
        message: "Socket cannot be established!"
      };
    }
  }

  send(message) {
    this.stompClient.send(message.url, JSON.stringify(message.params));
  }
}
```

Angular subscriber class implementation:

**Note: This class is used to bind subscribe routines to stomp client!**

```
export class Subscriber {
  constructor(private url: string = "", private callback: any) {
  }

  get URL() {
    return this.url;
  }

  get CALLBACK() {
    return this.callback;
  }
}
```

WebsocketUtil usage:

**Note: This snippet of code is called after view init stage.**

```
this.webSocketUtil.connect([
      new Subscriber("/notif", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }),
      new Subscriber("/user", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      })
    ]);
```

The code above causes following error in web browser(both FF & chrome) console:

[image: Browser error!]

**Note: https://localhost/ws is accessible and returns "Welcome to SockJS!" message.**

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I solved the problem regarding points below:

1. Adding appropriate rewrite config to Apache2 config- I'd ignored it:(

   ```
   ...

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
   RewriteRule ^/ws/(.*)       ws://localhost:8080/ws/$1 [P,L]    

   ...
   ```
2. Adding permit-all permission to **/ws** requests in security configuration class:

   @Configuration 
   @EnableWebSecurity 
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   ```
   ...

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       ...
       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll();
       ...
   }
   ```

   }
3. Adding permit-all permission to SimpTypes  in websocket configuration class:

   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
   public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
       ...

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
       messages.simpTypeMatchers(SimpMessageType.CONNECT, SimpMessageType.SUBSCRIBE, SimpMessageType.HEARTBEAT,
               SimpMessageType.UNSUBSCRIBE, SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT).permitAll();
   }
   ```

   }